# Need help Facebook App and Page Tab height resizing using FB.Canvas.setSize

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to resize the Facebook app height and page tab height automatically upon page load, but it isn't working.

I'm sure there's something simple I'm doing wrong, but I can't identify it.

Here is the simplified code I'm using: *(`++++` indicates cut out code)*

```
<!DOCTYPE ++++ >
<html>
 <head>++++</head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">++++</div>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
   FB.init({appId: '++++', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
   FB.Canvas.setSize();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Under `Settings`, `Advanced`, `Canvas Settings`, `Canvas Height`, I checked the `fixed` option. (As far as I can see, there is no longer a `Settable` option, presumably it has been renamed.)

My app has fully loaded by the time I called that method.

From a little investigation, I can see that the app height, and page tab height becomes the correct size to begin with, then increases almost immediately to a height of `1200px`. (And my `fixed height` is set at `600px`.

**Update:** On the iframe code it says the following: `<iframe src="++ommited++?signed_request=++ommited++" frameborder="0" scrolling="AUTO" style="width:810px; height:1200px;padding:0px; margin:0px" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px"></iframe>`. As you can see it says `height:1200px;` which appears to be the problem.

**Update:** It appears that the app defaults to the size set in my app settings, then it immediately resizes to `1200px`. This occurs even when I remove the Facebook code for changing the app and page tab height.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You might to wait until FB.init completes to call FB.Canvas.setSize()

Comment: did you have any luck with this? I can't make it work for me either...

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if Canvas is loaded with `FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading()`

```
FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading( function(response) {
    console.log(response.time_delta_ms);
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
});
```

FB Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading/

Answer (score 1):

I have had this type of issue to resize my page tab inside an FB Page. In my case I did the **following changes** in my website's page, which I wanted to be rendered on my FB Page, as tab:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function()
        {
            FB.Canvas.setSize();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    ......
    ......
    ......
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        FB.init({
        appId: 'Your_App_Id', 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true
        });
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
#wrap { width: 600px; height: 390px; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
#frame { width: 800px; height: 520px; border: 1px solid black; }
#frame {
    zoom: 0.75;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.75);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have the canvas height set to „Settable (Default: 800px)” in your app settings, otherwise it’s not *supposed* to work.

Then, has your app fully loaded by the point you’re calling the method (in regards to all images, css etc. that may influence the page height)?

Otherwise, you might try FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow – that periodically checks your page’s height and adapts the iframe height.

Comment: Under `Settings`, `Advanced`, `Canvas Settings`, `Canvas Height`, I checked the `fixed` option. As far as I can see, there is no longer a `Settable` option, presumably it has been renamed. And my app has fully loaded by the time I called that method. And I will try the `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow` now and report back. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No luck, but from a little investigation, I can see that the app height, and page tab height becomes the correct size to begin with, then increases almost immediately to a height of `1200px`. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: It is intended to look like this: <http://jsfiddle.net/MrJasonzF/9juDk/embedded/result/>. It looks like that immediatly when I load, but then it suddenly changes (virtually immediatly) to look like this: <http://jsfiddle.net/MrJasonzF/DWsfW/embedded/result/>, except that it is the iframe itself that expands to `1200px`.

Comment: If you need an example if Facebook itself, tell me and I will set one up. Thanks

Comment: Links again (formatted them wrong) (still can't format them for some reason, but here are the correct URL's):
1) jsfiddle.net/MrJasonzF/9juDk/embedded/result/
2) jsfiddle.net/MrJasonzF/DWsfW/embedded/result/

Comment: On the iframe code it says the following: `<iframe src="++ommited++?signed_request=++ommited++" frameborder="0" scrolling="AUTO" style="width:810px; height:1200px;padding:0px; margin:0px" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px"></iframe>`. As you can see it says `height:1200px;` which appears to be the problem.

Comment: Just for your information, I am adding updates to the question not here now.